# Python ValueError with two pyc scripts

Tags: python, python-import, pyc

I have two Python scripts, let's call them `parent.py`, and `child.py`. `parent.py` inherits code from `child.py`.

I wanted to obfuscate the code against casual viewers (my audience), so I encoded them both as `pyc` files, then changed the extensions back to `.py`. However, whenever I run `parent.py`, it says `ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`.

I'm able to fix this error by changing `child.py` to `child.pyc`, however, I'd rather keep all files as `.py`. Does anyone know how I'd solve this?

Comment: You essentially can't. Also, the statement "parent.py inherits code from child.py" is meaningless. I think you mean one imports the other, but you need to say that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `'.py'` extension from [`importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES) to [`importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES). This would not allow you to run the `parent` bytecode directly from python with a `.py` extension. Instead, you could write a small driver that contained python code that would give no hint of the contents of your scripts:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourcelessFileLoader, SOURCE_SUFFIXES, BYTECODE_SUFFIXES
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

SOURCE_SUFFIXES.remove('.py')
BYTECODE_SUFFIXES.append('.py')
path = dirname(abspath(__file__))
loader = SourcelessFileLoader('__main__', join(path, 'parent.py'))
spec = spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
script = module_from_spec(spec)
loader.exec_module(script)
```

You could call this driver script directly, assuming it was in the same folder as your bytecode.